# The directory is not writable by server- Magento 1.9 - Images

Tags: magento-1.9, image-upload

Ok! so I have finally upgraded to **Magento 1.9** from **Magento 1.7** through cPanel files, it seems to work well until I tried to upload a picture then it comes up ' the directory is not writable by server' I know this is a permission thing.

what file do I have to change permission for to get this working?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Set 775 permissions to `media` and `var` folders recursively.

Comment: It didn't work..

Answer (score 0):

Use The following commands to set permissions, I hope so it's help you

> find . -type f -exec chmod 644 {} \;
>       find . -type d -exec chmod 755 {} \;
>       find ./var -type d -exec chmod 777 {} \;
>       find ./media -type d -exec chmod 777 {} \;
>       chmod 777 ./app/etc
>       chmod 644 ./app/etc/*.xml